# Retrieve the data from the database and save results as lines in java lists

Tags: java, database, oracle

I query Oracle database using Java where I select 500 rows 40 colums each. When I have it in the result set (rs) then I would like to save the results as flat lines into the java list. I have something like this:

```
    while(rs.next()){
        String row="";
        for(int i=1; i<=columnCount; i++){
            row += " " + rs.getString(i);           
        }
         javaLIst.add(row);
    }
```

It works fine but it's not efficient at all. It takes about 16 seconds so I cannot afford this because I do that many times.

Can anyone tell me how I can retrieve data from database and save results to the java list in a more efficient way, please?

Comment: It doesn't work fine. You're adding a partial line for each column of each row. And you're asking for index 0, which doesn't exist. Use a StringBuilder to improve the "it's slow" part. But the main problem is probably the network between your code and the database.

Comment: First, you should use StringBuilder when you are appending String in a loop

Comment: @JBNizet No I'm not asking for index 0 - that was a typo, sorry. I has been corrected.

Comment: But you're still adding way too much stuff in your list. Why don't you test your code before posting it and saying that it works fine?

Comment: @JBNizet I tested it and it works fine, which means it does what I want but does to long

Comment: Now that you edited your post after I pointed out the two errors it contained, yes, it does what you want. The point is that you should test **before** posting.

Comment: @EdXX As JB the Nizet pointed out, the two biggest culprits here are network latency (i.e. the time/effort to send the data from your database to Java), and the fact that you are using raw string concatenations instead of using something like `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.  You can try improving both of these and see what happens.

Comment: Beyong the database overhead and string concatenation another small point is the size of the underlying list. Usually beginners start with ArrayList leading to memcopy during resizing. As you know the size create the ArrayList with the wanted size as constructor argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar Issue earlier and I found that the problem is not with the logic or the way it was implemented. 
The issue was with the Fetch Size. Oracle JDBC (if I remember correctly) it is 10, so you are retrieving records from database after every 10 records i.e 50 times for 500 entries.

Increase the `Statement.Fetchsize` to let's say 50 and see if this improves your performance. Tune this parameter as per your performance requirements.

See if this link helps https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#i1023619

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all 40 columns concatenated as a single string, then I don't see a way around doing the concatenation somewhere.  One alternative to consider might be to build the string you want directly in Oracle, e.g.

```
SELECT col1 || ', ' || col2 || ', ' || ... || col40 AS output
FROM yourTable
```

Then, your Java code would only be concerned with a single string field `output`.  In addition to sparing Java from a lengthy concatenation for each record, you would also be saving some overhead in terms of sending the result set from Oracle to Java.

Following the comment by @JBNizet if you want to stick with your current approach, you can try using `StringBuilder` to do the concatenation instead of raw `String`:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    sb.append(rs.getString(0));
    for (int i=1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
        sb.append(", ").append(rs.getString(i));
    }
    // add a complete row string here
    javaList.add(sb.toString());
}
```

Comment: Creating the StringBuilder with a higher capacity will prevent copying.